# UITextField nextResponder only works once

Tags: ios, uitextfield, first-responder, uiresponder

I have multiple UITextField's and am trying to click next to switch between them.  I have set the tags for each one from 1-4.  When I run my code, it moves to the second one, but won't move to the third.  If I jump textField.tag + 2; it will jump to the third field, but it doesn't move on from there.  Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
theScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(theScrollView.frame.origin.x, theScrollView.frame.origin.y,
                                 theScrollView.frame.size.width, theScrollView.frame.size.height + 265 - 50); //resize

NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
// Try to find next responder
UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
if (nextResponder) {
    // Found next responder, so set it.
    [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
} else {
    // Not found, so remove keyboard.
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
return NO; // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that all `UITextField` objects have its delegate set? Have you tried to debug which value has `textfield`'s tag? Have you make sure that there are no duplicate tags in the view hierarchy? BTW, you should check that the `UIView` returned in `viewWithTag` is actually a `UITextField` object.

Comment: Wow, it was the delegate. I'm blind! Thanks! Want to post that as a response so I can chose the answer?

Comment: I have added the answer below. Appreciate your vote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would review the following items:

1. Check that all `UITextField` objects have its delegate set
2. Start the debugger and inspect the value of every `textfield`'s tag
3. Make sure that there are no duplicate tags in the view hierarchy
4. Test that the `UIView` object returned in `viewWithTag:` is actually a `UITextField` object.